# Tomcat 7 deployment preventing me from making minor changes

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, war

Just moved from Tomcat 5 to Tomcat 7 and having problems with deployment.

I intially deploy my application widget by copying `widget.war` into webapps, this works, Tomcat deploys and explodes the war.

**The problem comes with when I want to make *changes*.**

If I redeploy the war everything works, but because I am uploading the war to a remote server this can be quite slow. So if I am just changing one class I just copy the new class directly into the exploded folder structure, then shutdown and restart Tomcat but it has no effect.

I think I've worked out it is because the widget.war gets redeployed so my newer class get replaced by the older version of the class in the widget.war. So then I manually deleted the widget.war so it couldn't get overwritten but then on shutdown/startup I have no widget folder at all. it disappears !

Why is this, this did not happen with Tomcat 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete the .war file while tomcat is running it will also delete the exploded directory.
You may either first shutdown tomcat, delete the .war file and then start again or better, why not just unzip the .war file by hand into the webapps folder (but do not put the .war file in webapps).

Comment: Thankyou for explaining the issue. I dont want to shutdown tomcat more than I have to though as its a live server, I may try your unzip from another folder solution.

Answer (score 2):

Deploying single-file fixes this way is a sure way to get into a situation where you can't reconstruct what's running on the server and that's a pain in the but to maintain.

The clean solution is to *only ever deploy full war files*.

Now you say that copying it to the remote server is slow? There's a simple-ish solution to this:

Keep a copy of the latest war file somewhere on the remote server (outside of the Tomcat webapps directory) and `rsync` the new version over it: this should be much faster, as only changed data needs to be transferred. Then deploy from that directory.

Comment: I still build the whole war everytime I just dont need to copy over the whole war but I will look into your rysnc idea. By deploy I asume you mean just copy the local widget.war into webapps folder

Comment: Using rsync is a good idea, you can unpack the generated .war file on your machine and rsync to the unpacked directory in your server's webapp folder.

Comment: I thought the idea was to use rsync on the war not the unpacked war.

Comment: @PaulTaylor: yes, that's my idea. It works pretty well, I've even used a more extensive scheme with multiple versions on the server (and the `--fuzzy` rsync option), but simply rsyncing the new version over the old version should work just fine.

Comment: Thansk well both are good answers, but I just the other as correct because it explained why what I'm currently doing doesnt work.

Comment: to rsync the .war file is a great idea.